# How to pass `props` data from parent to child on react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props

I want to pass my `props` data from parent to child when it will route to new path.
I tried some https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105 but not actually worked when i passed it through `{...props}`.

any help would be greatful.

//App.js

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="navbar">
          <h2 className="center">Tiny Book Library</h2>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={PostBook}/>
          <Route exact path="/abc" render={props => <AllBook someProp="2" {...props} />} />
        </Switch>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

//Allbook.js

```
class AllBook extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
      }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {Object.keys(this.props.posts).length !== 0 ?  <h1 className="post-heading">All books</h1> : ""}  {/*To check if array is empty or not*/}

                {/*Arrow function to map each added object*/}
                {this.props.posts.map((post) =>(

                    <div key={post.id}>

                        {post.editing ? <EditComponent post={post} key={post.id}/> :
                            <Post key={post.id} post={post}/>}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        posts: state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AllBook);
```

//reducer

```
const postReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_BOOK':
            return state.concat([action.data]);
        case 'DELETE_BOOK':
            return state.filter((post) => post.id !== action.id);
        case 'EDIT_BOOK':
            return state.map((post)=>post.id === action.id ? {...post, editing:!post.editing} : post)
        case 'UPDATE':
            return state.map((post)=>{
                if(post.id === action.id){
                    return{
                        ...post,
                        title: action.data.newTitle,
                        number:action.data.newNumber,
                        author:action.data.newAuthor,
                        description:action.data.newDescription,
                        editing: !post.editing
                    }
                } 
                else return post;
            })
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default postReducer;
```

Comment: Which prop from the parent are you having issues passing from parent to child? If it’s posts then I’d have to ask why pass posts if you are getting posts from your Redux store. If not, then that’s a different issue.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yes from `postbook` i want to pass it to `allBook` so that all my books will be visible there. But on changing to router  `props` data are not storing any value.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yes i am getting `posts` from `redux` store. What i need to change then?

Comment: Can I ask why don't you connect AllBook to redux, in order to receive posts list when is ready?

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia mmm not sure. What do you think i need to change here ? I have updated my code.

Comment: Just looking at the new code, seems to work. I don't think you have to pass `posts` from App component. 
This way any time your posts change, components subscribed to it should be updated. P.D: you are receiving full state in mapStateToProps, try to destructure it like `({posts}) => ` for performance reasons.

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia could you please add you answer.

Comment: Hi Tanmoy, cana you please also add _PostBook_ component's code that you use to change routes to _AllBook_? I have something in my mind I wanna verify, specially the

Comment: @SultanH. here it is .. updated

Comment: Great, thanks, I can't find anything in the _PostBook_ component about changing the route to _AllBook_, so, how do you change the route from _PostBook_ to _AllBook_?

Comment: @SultanH. currently i am checking manually with `/abc`

Comment: So, you basically write `http://localhost:3000/abc` from the URL bar in the browseR?

Comment: @SultanH. yes currently i am checking like this only. but will change later

Comment: I have added an answer below explaining what happens, please check it, and let me know if you need help setting up _Link_ in your app.

Comment: @SultanH. yes please it will be really helpful then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196747/discussion-between-sultan-h-and-tanmoy-sarkar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE #1: Adding a *Link* for the sake of a Correct Page Transition:**

- **First:** `import` *Link* component at the beginning of your *App.js*:

`import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'`

- **Second:** Add *Link* components to route between both pages:

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="navbar">
          <h2 className="center">Tiny Book Library</h2>
          <Link to="/">Post A Book</Link>
          <Link to="/abc">All Books</Link>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={PostBook}/>
          <Route exact path="/abc" render={props => <AllBook someProp="2" {...props} />} />
        </Switch>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

There is probably nothing wrong with the code above, the cause of this behavior is changing the route manually from the browser.

Which causes the problem.

Explaining further:

- You post the data from the form in *PostBook*.
- The data is stored in the *reducer*.
- You change the url manually from the browser, you lose all the data you have submitted to the *reducer*, this is not an error, nor an expected behavior, because doing that will request entirely new app for you, thus, ZERO DATA.

Please read about [Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md), to change the url properly so you can test your code whether it works or not.

Comment: Here is a good [reference](https://www.taniarascia.com/using-react-router-spa/) for you to get things sattle about Routing in a Single Page Application.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the `react-router` [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/api/Route/render-func), the parameters in the `render` function prop are the router props: i.e. the props that the `Route` component would normally get: `history`, `location` and more.

You don't want that, you want to pass your own/parent props:
\ App.js

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    const myProps = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="navbar">
          <h2 className="center">Tiny Book Library</h2>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={PostBook}/>
          <Route exact path="/abc" render={() => <AllBook someProp="2" {...myProps} />} />
        </Switch>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if would be helpfull. 
Subscribe Allbook to posts, in your case looks like your entire redux store is just posts, or at least you are passing all redux state to `posts`.

```
class AllBook extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
      }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {Object.keys(this.props.posts).length !== 0 ?  <h1 className="post-heading">All books</h1> : ""}  {/*To check if array is empty or not*/}

                {/*Arrow function to map each added object*/}
                {this.props.posts.map((post) =>(

                    <div key={post.id}>

                        {post.editing ? <EditComponent post={post} key={post.id}/> :
                            <Post key={post.id} post={post}/>}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// (state) => { return { posts: state.posts } }; Should also work.
const mapStateToProps = ({ posts }) => ({ posts });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AllBook);
```